# couchdb installed via snapd on OpenSuse not working

Tags: opensuse, couchdb-2.0

I've installed couchDb 2.0 via snap onto OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

```
sudo snap install couchdb
```

Then I ran

```
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
```

Everything works fine until I logout.  In my new session I cannot get couchDb running.
Would anyone know of a solution please?

Some more info:

```
systemctl status snapd
```

gives:

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
>   Active: active (running) since Sat 2018-07-28 16:33:45 NZST; 4min 10s ago
>
> May 12 20:31:04 hobbes systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
>   May 12 20:31:04 hobbes snapd[4705]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled but some features are missing: dbus
>   May 12 20:31:04 hobbes snapd[4705]: 2018/05/12 20:31:04.773100 daemon.go:323: started snapd/2.32.5-1.10 (series 16; classic; devmode) opensuse-tumbleweed/20180502 (amd>
>   May 12 20:31:04 hobbes systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.

Comment: Some feedback from #suse channel: CouchDB snap failure is due to apparmor, it seems to block starting the service. Try running; sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*      and then snap start couchdb. To fix it so you don't have to run it everytime; save https://paste.opensuse.org/33232726 as /etc/systemd/system/snapd.apparmor.service and systemctl enable snapd.apparmor.service   - then reboot and try snap start couchdb   send cookies if it works.

Comment: snapd temporary fix for apparmor

[Unit]
Description=Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
Requisite=snapd.service
After=apparmor.service
ConditionSecurity=apparmor
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd-apparmor start
RemainAfterExit=yes
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some feedback from #suse channel:

> CouchDB snap failure is due to apparmor, it seems to block starting the service. Try running; sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/*      and then snap start couchdb
>   To fix it so you don't have to run it everytime; save https://paste.opensuse.org/33232726 as /etc/systemd/system/snapd.apparmor.service and systemctl enable snapd.apparmor.service   - then reboot and try snap start couchdb   send cookies if it works.

from the expiring pastie:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=sysinit.target
Requisite=snapd.service
After=apparmor.service
ConditionSecurity=apparmor

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd-apparmor start
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```